# Handle XML with and without a Default Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I am writing a piece of code in C# that will receive XML and will pull out some values.  When the XML I receive has a default namespace then I must use a XmlNamespaceManager.

```
XmlDocument requestXml = new XmlDocument();
requestXml.LoadXml(request);
XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(requestXml.NameTable);
xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns0", requestXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
metadata.Identifier = requestXml.SelectSingleNode("//ns0:Identifier[1]", xmlNamespaceManager).InnerText;
```

But when the namespace has a prefix than this code breaks, but it works without the namespace manager.

```
XmlDocument requestXml = new XmlDocument();
requestXml.LoadXml(request);
metadata.Identifier = requestXml.SelectSingleNode("//Identifier[1]").InnerText;
```

Is it reasonable for me to expect to know whether the xml namespace will have a prefix?  If not, how can I build more robust code that doesn't care if the namespace has a prefix?  Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**
It is my understanding that these three are the same.
Example1:

```
<Node1 xmlns="myNamespace">
    <Node2>
        <Node3></Node3>
    </Node2>
</Node1>
```

Example2:

```
<ns0:Node1 xmlns:ns0="myNamespace">
    <Node2>
        <Node3></Node3>
    </Node2>
</ns0:Node1>
```

Example3:

```
<ns0:Node1 xmlns:ns0="myNamespace">
    <ns0:Node2>
        <ns0:Node3></ns0:Node3>
    </ns0:Node2>
</ns0:Node1>
```

Instead of asking how C# can treat these the same (I know C# has trouble with default namespaces) a better question is what checks do I perform to ensure I am covering all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

One would assume that there is strong relationship between namespace prefixes in XML and namespace prefixes in XPath but there is none.

Namespace prefix of node in XML: could be empty or not, empty prefix maps to currently default namespace. That default namespace for *current element* could be either an empty  namespace (if there is no `xmlns="urn:somenamespace"` on current/parent node) or some particular namespace if `xmlns` is present.

Sample:

```
<root>
   <child1 xmlns="urn:ns1">
       <inner xmlns="urn:reallyDeep" />
   </child1>
   <child2 />
<root>
```

Empty namespace prefix maps to:

- `root` - empty namespace (default)
- `child1` - `urn:ns1`, full node name can be represented as `{urn:ns1}child1`
- `child2` - empty namespace coming from parent (`root`)
- `inner` - `urn:reallyDeep` because it is redefined on that node with `xmlns:`.

Now XPath namespace prefixes are a bit simple because empty prefix always maps to empty namespace.

To select `inner` node in the sample above one need to select nodes from 3 namespaces: empty, `urn:ns1`, `urn:reallyDeep`. So namespace manager need to be constructed with 3 prefixes. Default empty one is always there, so need to add just two more. Note that prefixes in XPath have no relation to prefixes in XML - common practice is to match prefixes for some "well known" namespaces (like `xsi`), but it is strictly personal choice.

```
 p1 -> urn:ns1
 p2 -> urn:reallyDeep

 /root/p1:child1/p2:child2
```

When writing code it may be safe to explicitly define mapping instead of trying to take one from the XML unless you building XPath samples based on the XML:

```
 xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("p1", "urn:ns1");
 xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns0", "urn:reallyDeep");
```

Note that XML may use single namespace prefix for all namespace (empty prefix or any other one). I.e. following XML is identical from XML point of view to sample earlier even if it uses prefixes:

```
<root>
   <a:child1 xmlns="urn:ns1">
       <a:inner xmlns:a="urn:reallyDeep" />
   </a:child1>
   <child2 />
<root>
```

Note that if you don't care about namespaces and prefixes (you really not using XML properly in this case) you can use `local-name` XPath function to compare just names.

Comment: The xml will always have "someNamespace" but isn't it legal to assign any prefix to this (xmlns:ns0=someNamespace, xmlns:urn=someNamespace).  Then adding a namespace to the namespace manager will break because I am trying to add the wrong prefix to it.

Comment: @Joe - clearly it was not useful answer  - I'll delete it soon. Someone else should try to explain that there is no relationship between prefixes in XML and XPath. Sorry about wasting your time.

Comment: No, your answer is helpful.  I'm just still trying to figure out how to code for an unknown prefix.

Comment: @Joe - I'll keep it than... but it look like it still did not get to may point: the only thing matters is namespace, whatever way you name prefixes does not matter as long it produce valid XPath/valid XML. It may be easier to understand if you pretend that there is no prefixes in XML and each prefix replaced with full namespace...